# Refreshing javascript page without refreshing HTML, but as windows' width changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The opacity of my nav bar changes as I scroll, and the rate  at which it changes is based on the width of the window. Once the page is loaded, I tried changing the width but the opacity change rate is still the same. Is there a way for the opacity change rate parameters to change automatically without refreshing the page?

```
if ($(window).width() > 1060) {
   fadenumber = 500;
}
else if ($(window).width() > 800){
    fadenumber = 600;
}
else if ($(window).width() > 600){
   fadenumber = 400;
}
else {
    fadenumber = 200;
}

$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    $('.navbar').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / fadenumber));
    var fadeStart=0 ,fadeUntil=fadenumber;
        var offset = $(document).scrollTop(),opacity=0 
        ;
        if( offset<=fadeStart ){
            opacity=1;
        }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
            opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
        }
        $('.icon').css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an event for when the window or a DOM object gets resized.

So you can create an event listener that does this.

Here's how to get the size and add a listener. (Also here's a more in depth jsfiddle I wrote for this: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/65mL7btd/)

```
var outputDiv = $('#outputjq');

function callback(){
    outputDiv.html(window.innerWidth);
}

$(window).on('resize', callback);

callback();
```

if you want to change the rate, you can augment the rate inside of the callback.

```
function callback2(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1060) {
       fadenumber = 500;
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 800){
        fadenumber = 600;
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 600){
       fadenumber = 400;
    }
    else {
        fadenumber = 200;
    }
}

var fadenumber;

$(window).on('resize', callback2);

callback2();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var onScroll;
$(document).on('scroll', onScroll = function () {
    $('.navbar').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / fadenumber));
    var fadeStart=0 ,fadeUntil=fadenumber;
        var offset = $(document).scrollTop(),opacity=0 
        ;
        if( offset<=fadeStart ){
            opacity=1;
        }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
            opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
        }
        $('.icon').css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
$(document).on('resize', function () {
if ($(window).width() > 1060) {
       fadenumber = 500;
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 800){
        fadenumber = 600;
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 600){
       fadenumber = 400;
    }
    else {
        fadenumber = 200;
    }
onScroll();
});
```

[You should make variables global first]

Interpreter will check the width after resize.
You can copypaste your resize function code (without onScroll();) into scroll function, so it will check the width also when the document is being scrolled.

**EDIT**

You can put () after onResize function to make sure, variables will be set when document is ready (and you can put all in $(document).ready()), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
var onResize;
    $(document).on('resize', onResize = function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 1060) {
           fadenumber = 500;
        }
        else if ($(window).width() > 800){
            fadenumber = 600;
        }
        else if ($(window).width() > 600){
           fadenumber = 400;
        }
        else {
            fadenumber = 200;
        }
    }()); // () to launch function right after it's declared
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($(window).width() > 1060) {
   fadenumber = 500;
}
else if ($(window).width() > 800){
    fadenumber = 600;
}
else if ($(window).width() > 600){
   fadenumber = 400;
}
else {
    fadenumber = 200;
}

changeOpacityRate();

$(document).on('scroll', function () 
{
    changeOpacityRate();
});

function changeOpacityRate()
{
    $('.navbar').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / fadenumber));
    var fadeStart=0 ,fadeUntil=fadenumber;
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop(),opacity=0 ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart )
    {
        opacity=1;
    }
    else if( offset<=fadeUntil )
    {
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    $('.icon').css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
}
```